# Hyperlink in Xamarin.Forms Label

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

This works fine if it present only 1 hyperlink, but issue occurs more than one hyperlink are rendered and below issue occured

> --------- Stack trace ---------   at System.String.Substring (System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 length) [0x0004c] in
>   :0    at
>   MPI.UI.Mobile.Converter.HtmlLabelConverter.ProcessString
>   (System.String rawText) [0x0004b] in
>   :0    at
>   MPI.UI.Mobile.Converter.HtmlLabelConverter.Convert (System.Object
>   value, System.Type targetType, System.Object parameter,
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00008] in
>   :0    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Binding.GetSourceValue (System.Object value, System.Type
>   targetPropertyType) [0x0001b] in <036ea626158e48a4b8dcc52d0593c6a6>:0 
>   at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (System.Object
>   sourceObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target,
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Boolean fromTarget)
>   [0x001ce] in <036ea626158e48a4b8dcc52d0593c6a6>:0    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (System.Boolean fromTarget)
>   [0x0003e] in <036ea626158e48a4b8dcc52d0593c6a6>:0    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.b__49_0
>   () [0x00000] in <036ea626158e48a4b8dcc52d0593c6a6>:0    at
>   Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in
>   :0    at
>   Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
>   native__this) [0x00009] in :0    at
>   (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.18(intptr,intptr)
>   ------------------------------- --------- Message --------- Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name:
>   length ------------------------------- --------- Source ---------
>   mscorlib -------------------------------

**HtmlLabelConverter**

Add the following HtmlLabelConverter. This supports multiple  links in a body of text, but not any other HTML elements.

```
public class HtmlLabelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var formatted = new FormattedString();

        foreach (var item in ProcessString((string)value))
            formatted.Spans.Add(CreateSpan(item));

        return formatted;
    }

    private Span CreateSpan(StringSection section)
    {
        var span = new Span()
        {
            Text = section.Text
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(section.Link))
        {
            span.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
            {
                Command = _navigationCommand,
                CommandParameter = section.Link
            });
            span.TextColor = Color.Blue;
        }

        return span;
    }

    public IList<StringSection> ProcessString(string rawText)
    {
        const string spanPattern = @"(<a.*?>.*?</a>)";

        MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(rawText, spanPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

        var sections = new List<StringSection>();

        var lastIndex = 0;

        foreach (Match item in collection)
        {
            *****sections.Add(new StringSection() { Text = rawText.Substring(lastIndex, item.Index) });*****  <!--Here the issue occurs -->
            *****lastIndex += item.Index + item.Length;*****  <!--Here the issue occurs -->

            // Get HTML href 
            var html = new StringSection()
            {
                Link = Regex.Match(item.Value, "(?<=href=\\\")[\\S]+(?=\\\")").Value,
                Text = Regex.Replace(item.Value, "<.*?>", string.Empty)
            };

            sections.Add(html);
        }

        ***sections.Add(new StringSection() { Text = rawText.Substring(lastIndex) });***   <!--Here the issue occurs -->

        return sections;
    }

    public class StringSection
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
    }

     private ICommand _navigationCommand = new Command<string>((url) =>
     {
         Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url));
     });

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

Then XAML, i would call it like so.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <local:HtmlLabelConverter x:Key="HtmlLabelConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Please show us how you are using the converter in code. Also, if you look at the end of the stack trace, you can see the error that you have - `Message --------- Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length`

You can easily debug the converter and see why the index goes outside the range.

Comment: Hi , could you share a sample project link here ? I will check that in local site .